BlueStacks 5 не запускается на виртуальной машине
Возникла такая проблема, выключили свет, на пару часов, запускаю все как обычно.
Но при запуске BlueStacks 5й версии, на своей виртуальной машине, он перестал открываться.
Такое ощущение что я уже все перепробовал. Но есть нюансы, на 11й винде не открывается совсем, после проделанных моих манипуляций по установке винды 10 на соседний ссд диск, на одной виртуалке он вроде как запустился, но на 3х других нет.
Подскажите может кто сталкивался, есть ли решение.
